# Cannot refresh datagridview - an object reference is required

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've been trying to refresh my datagridview on `form1` each time `form2` closes.

On form 2, I have a close event handler that calls the static method **RefreshGridView** (which is located in form 1).

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Form1.RefreshGridView();
}
```

On form 1, I have a static method **RefreshGridView** to refresh the grid as below.

```
public static void RefreshGridView()
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

However each time, I try run my code, I get these error messages at the following lines:

```
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

**Error:** An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PGPTool.Form1.dataGridView1'.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

**Error:** An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PGPTool.Form1.dataGridView1'.

How can I go about resolving this?

Comment: You cannot access an instance field (in this case `dataGridView1`) from a static method. Does `Form2` not have a reference to `Form1`?

Comment: Is `Form1` responsible for creating instances of `Form2` or is some other class responsible for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RefreshGridView` shouldn't be a static method, it should be an instance method.  And a reference to the instance of `form1` should be given to `form2`.  This is because you want this method to make changes to elements on `form1`, which are part of that *instance*.  (For example, if you have 2 instances of `form1`, a static method wouldn't know which to modify.  Or if you have *no* instance, it wouldn't have *anything* to modify.)

So the method should be changed to:

```
public void RefreshGridView()
```

And in `form2` you should have a way to hold a reference to `form1`.  Something like this:

```
private Form1 Form1Instance { get; set; }
```

Since you want to invoke something on this reference every time `form2` closes, then is it safe to assume that `form2` should *require* a reference to `form1` every time it's created?  If so, then you can enforce that in the constructor of `form2`.  Something like this:

```
public Form2(Form1 form1Instance)
{
    // perform any error checking and/or null checking on form1Instance here

    Form1Instance = form1Instance;
}
```

Then in the event on `form2` you can call the method on that instance:

```
Form1Instance.RefreshGridView();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `Form2` to be given references to `Form1`, there is another way to do it: event listeners. These will only work if `Form1` is responsible for creating instances of `Form2` or some central code is responsible for creating both.

So here's how you would do it (if `Form1` is creating instances of `Form2`):

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.FormClosed += (o, e) => { RefreshGridView(); };
//show f2 or do whatever else you need to do with it
```

If some other class is doing it, you'd have to modify that like this:

```
//f1 is the instance of Form1
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.FormClosed += (o, e) => { f1.RefreshGridView(); };
//show f2 or do whatever else you need to do with it
```

As I mentioned in the comments and David mentions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845701/1346943), you need to modify the signature of your `RefreshGridView()` method to remove the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Treat your Form2 as a Dialog, it's so much easier. When you've finished dealing with your `Form2` call `DialogResult.OK`. It will also close it.

If your form1 datagridview is bound already to your bs bindingsource, you probably don't need to create a new bindingSource, just query your data again.

```
public void RefreshGridView()
{
    var q = //your query

    bs.dataSource = q
}
```

Back in `Form1` you have something like this, and you call it every time you want to open `Form2`:

```
private void openForm2()
{
    var f2 = new Form2(); //create new form2
    var formResult = f2.ShowDialog(); //open as Dialog and check result after close event
    if (formResult == DialogResult.OK) //check form2 dialog result
    {
        //form2 gave OK, I can update my DGV and display msg
        MessageBox.Show("DGV will be updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        //update my DGV
        RefreshGridView();
    }
    else
    {
        //form2 passed Cancel or something else, not good
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 Closed but nothing happened.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```